# Trying to run test script using Rational Quality Manager

Tags: clearcase, jazz, rational-team-concert, ibm-jazz

Machine : windows 7
Started : RQM command line adapter.
When initiated test from RQM , I recieve Exit code 1 on the windows machine on which adapter was on.

log file in RQM says:
System error 5 has occurred.
Access is denied.
Bad file descriptor

while running the installation manager thru commandline everything worked fine, Inintiated adapter using the same credentials still its not working.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error `(Access is denied. Bad file descriptor)` could be caused by the CLA JAR files being read-only.

Also, the CLA creates temporary files in the directory defined in the java.io.tmpdir system property (on UNIX systems the default value of this property is typically `/tmp` or `/var/tmp;` on Windows systems it is typically defined in the `%Temp%` system variable (e.g. `C:\WINNT\TEMP` or `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp`)), which could be full or not sufficient permissions.